# Win32-Api CreateFile(...) in C++ failed

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, device, createfile

The following code is working under one PC but not on an other PC. Both PC's have Windows 7 as their OS.

```
char device_name[] = "\\\\.\\interception00";
printf("device_name: %s \n", device_name);

device_array[i].handle = CreateFile(device_name, GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

DWORD error = GetLastError();
printf("GetLastError (Number): %d, ", error);

if (error == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
{
    printf("error == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND \n");
}
else if (error == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    printf("error == ERROR_SUCCESS \n");
}
else
{
    printf("error == UNBEKANNT \n");
}
```

The Output of the PC that is successfully opens the File:

```
device_name: \\.\interception00
GetLastError (Number): 0, error == ERROR_SUCCESS
```

The other PC is not able to open the File. The Output is:

```
device_name: \\.\interception00
GetLastError (Number): 2, error == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Does someone have a clue why this happens ? Maybe it is a problem of insufficient rights ?

Comment: Probably the second computer isn't running the driver that creates that device special file.

Comment: Your error checking is somewhat bogus. Only call `GetLastError` if the API call fails. You don't check for failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From MSDN's [`CreateFile()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> OPEN_EXISTING
>
> Opens a file or device, only if it exists.
>
> If the specified file or device does not exist, the function fails and the last-error code is set to ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (2).

So this means that `\\\\.\\interception00` exists on one computer but not the other. Try to look with some other program that is normally capable of opening the File/Device.

Or just fix that `\\\\.\\interception00` is not available.

Comment: Do you know a way/tool to watch all the available devices ?

Comment: I dont. Sorry. Someone else?

Comment: I know now. It's a software called WinObj :)

Comment: Do you know how the fix so that \\\\.\\interception00 is aviable ?

Comment: I dont even know what this special-file is for (special-files can be used for anything) and there is no info about interception00 on the web. There is a driver on the other computer that provides this path. You need that software on the second computer too. If you dont know which software that is then I would suggest (1) you use agent ransack to search the whole harddrive for "interception", if you didn't find out which software provides interception00 then try the same thing by using grepWin to search the whole harddrive.